# mvc3controlstoolkit treeview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, treeview, viewmodel

How can I pass the recursive list to MVC3ControlsToolkit TreeView? I've found lots of example defining the items and sub-items manually but I need to bind it to the model. My model looks like this:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode()
    {
        child = new HashSet<TreeNode>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TreeNode> child { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Bind it from database to your model or from client postback data to your model?

Comment: i've done the data binding. i've the function that returns the list after binding the data to the database. My problem is that i don't know how to pass the parameters to the treeviewfor(in mvc controls toolkit) in the view.

Comment: is that "*returns the list*" a flat list and not hierarchy maybe. Seems more likely since database data is almost definitely flat...

Comment: the list is working fine. I've tested the treeview using treeview helper from Matt Hidinger. But now i want to display the treeview using mvccontrolstoolkit. I want to know how the parameters need to be passed in treeviewfor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. Just needed to pass the IList containing recursive list instead of Icollection. Thanks to frankabbruzzese!!

Comment: After the 2.3 release (included) the treeview should work fine also with ICollections